# Wrong file input

Tags: java

I have to enter string x in reverse order, but it outputs null. Why and how to fix it?
Sorry in advance for the name of the variables, but also for the double loop (I know it's bad, but this is the only thing that came to my mind)

The main question is why null is entered in the file

```
public static void OutputOfFile(char[] x)throws IOException {
        File file = new File("test");
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());

        out.print(x);
        out.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String x = reader.readLine();
        char[] x1 = x.toCharArray();
        char[] x2 = new char[x1.length];
        for(int i = x1.length - 1; i < -1; i--) {
            for (int k = 0; k > x1.length; k++) {
                x2[i] = x1[k];
            }
        }
        OutputOfFile(x2);
    }
```

Comment: By "outputs null", do you mean "outputs nothing", or "outputs, literally,  the word 'null'"?

Comment: I enter "sad" outputs "nullnullnull", I enter "asdf" outputs "nullnullnullnull"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is with your loop, you need to iterate in one loop instead of an inner loop:

```
public static void OutputOfFile(char[] x) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(""test"");
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());

    out.print(x);
    out.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String x = reader.readLine();
    char[] x1 = x.toCharArray();
    char[] x2 = new char[x1.length];
    
    for (int i = x1.length - 1, k = 0; i >= 0; i--, k++) {
        x2[k] = x1[i];
    }

    OutputOfFile(x2);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works.What happened then in the double loop that made everything go bad?

Comment: You did something weird, all of the values which assigned to the index of array is the same which is the last value of k index.